# Google Sheets: IF and Date formula not working

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm calculating annual holiday accrual.

All holiday resets at the start of the calendar year.

If a staff member started after 01.01.2017 they will have a lower holiday entitlement for the year.

I'm trying to create a formula which says:

If this cell's date is after 01.01.2017 return that cells date. Otherwise, set it at 01.01.2017.

(so basically, I don't care when they started if it was before 01 Jan 2017 because all my following calculations will be based off the first day of the year)

Here it is:

```
=if(T21<date(1,1,2017),T21,"01/01/2017")
```

No matter what is in the cell, it is returning 01/01/2017.If I change the < to > it returns cell T21 in all cases.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have the DATE() values mixed up.  Try:

```
=if(T21<date(2017,1,1),T21,"01/01/2017")
```

DATE() is year, month, day

Also, you may want to use DATEVALUE() on the FALSE value to force the returned item to a date:

```
=if(T21<date(2017,1,1),T21,DATEVALUE("01/01/2017"))
```

Answer (score 0):

"01.01.2017" is not a valid date in Google docs. You need to change `.` to `/`.

```
             =DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(T21,".","/"))

            =IF(DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(T21,".","/"))<DATEVALUE(date(2017,1,1)),T21,"01/01/2017")
```